# devise 1.3.4 and rack-ssl + thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise, thin

hi i've tried to add ssl to my rails (3.0.9) app... 
i'm using divise for authentication and have installed the rack-ssl gem, my test server is thin.

in #application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
require 'rack/ssl'
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module myapp
class Application < Rails::Application
config.middleware.use Rack::SSL
```

im starting thin:

```
thin start -V -e production --ssl
```

ssl works, but if i try to login or logout i get an 302 error (moved temporaly) with an refer to a non ssl url (http instead https)